# Estimating the complexity of recursive function

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, master-theorem

```
void f(int n) {
    if (!n) return;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        f(n/12);
    g(n,3);
}

void g(int n, int i) {
    if (!i) return;
    for (int j=n; j>0; --j) {
        g(n,i-1);
    }
}
```

I am trying to estimate the complexity of this function.This is the way I do it:

1. Estimate g complexity. It depends on the value of i, and each entry raises n cycle entries, so the whole complexity is Θ(n^3).
2. Now starting with f. T(n) = 8*(T/12) + g(n, 3). Now applying Master Theorem. log8(12) < 3 (f's complexity degree), so the whole complexity of f is Θ(n^3).

Is this the right solution or do I need to consider anything else?

Comment: Should g not be Θ(n^i) ?

Comment: Yes. In this case i equals 3, that is why i have written it like n^3.

Comment: So if every f starts one g and multiple f, should the complexity of f not be larger than g?

Answer (score 0):

Since `T(n)` terminates when `n = 0`, the recursion of `T` must be `log12(T)` deep (ignoring rounding and off-by-one etc.)

If we expand the series, given your result for `g`:

[image]

The second term in the brackets is vanishingly small so can be ignored. Thus total complexity is `Θ(n^3)`.